# transition animation background color

Tags: windows-phone-7, toolkit

I am using WP7 control toolkit transition animation in my app.  My app's pages are all light blue in color but when the transition animation (say, turnstile) is used, during the animation, a black background shows up.  How can I make this background during transition to be light blue?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm assuming your `PhoneApplicationPage`'s have a `Background` of `Blue`.  If that is the case, then open up `App.xaml.cs` and find the line that says:

```
RootFrame = new TransitionFrame();
```

Directly after that, place the following statement:

```
RootFrame.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
```

That should ensure that your app looks consistent during animations.  You can see a full sample project here: http://wp7-developer.com/quick-tip/quick-tip-ensuring-the-background-color-remains-consistent-during-a-transition/

Comment: That did it.  Thanks for the nice tip and for figuring it out.

Comment: This still works in Windows Phone 8.1 (where a Frame object is used instead of the TransitionFrame).